# Onsager reciprocal relations and Darcy's permeability tensor for anisotropic porous media

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, porous-media

The Wikipedia entry on soil [tensor permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(earth_sciences)#Tensor_permeability) states that

> The tensor is symmetric by the Onsager reciprocal relations.

[Bear & Cheng (2010, p122)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-6682-5) state that:

> The hydraulic conductivity tensor, $K_{ij}$, is *symmetric*, i.e., $K_{ij}=K_{ji}$
> , and *positive definite*... The fact that the tensor $K_{ij}$ is symmetric is a consequence of the *Onsager reciprocal relationship*,
> which is applicable to cases in which a force produces a flux of
> one extensive quantity produces also fluxes of other extensive
> quantities.

I've been reading [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations#Example:_Fluid_system) on the Wikipedia page on [Onsager reciprocal relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations), and this is where I would like some help.

**Question:** How to show that the permeability tensor (or hydraulic conductivity tensor) of [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law) is symmetric and positive definite? How to replace the equations shown in the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations#Example:_Fluid_system) for Fick's law with the ones of [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law)?

It seems that to answer this question, I need some help clarifying what exactly are the "Onsager matrix of phenomenological coefficients" ($L_{\alpha \beta}$) in the [equations reported on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations#The_phenomenological_equations):

$$J_u = L_{uu}\nabla (1/T)+L_{u\rho}\nabla(-\mu/T)$$
$$J_\rho=L_{\rho u}\nabla(1/T)+L_{\rho \rho}\nabla(-\mu/T)$$

In other words, how are the $L_{\alpha \beta}$ terms related to the thermal conductivity $k$ and coefficient of diffusion $D$ terms in this example?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594366/226902