# Physical meaning of phenomenological equations for transport coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

Luttinger in his [publication about the theory of thermal transport coefficients](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.135.A1505) write phenomenological equations in the form
$$
j_\alpha(r) = L_{\alpha\gamma}^{(1)}\bigg[E_\gamma-\frac{1}{e}T\nabla_\gamma(\frac{\mu}{T})\bigg]+L_{\alpha\gamma}^{(2)}T\nabla_\gamma(\frac{1}{T}) + \tilde{L}_{\alpha\gamma}^{(2)}(-\nabla_\gamma\psi) \tag{2.13a}
$$
$$
j_\alpha^E(r) = L_{\alpha\gamma}^{(3)}\bigg[E_\gamma-\frac{1}{e}T\nabla_\gamma(\frac{\mu}{T})\bigg]+L_{\alpha\gamma}^{(4)}T\nabla_\gamma(\frac{1}{T}) + \tilde{L}_{\alpha\gamma}^{(4)}(-
\nabla_\gamma\psi) \tag{2.13b}
$$
where $j_\alpha$ is an electrical current density and $j_\alpha^E$ is a thermal current density in $\alpha$ direction. $E_\gamma$ is externally applied electrical field in $\gamma$ direction. $\mu$ is chemical potential. $\psi$ is the gravitational potential field (defined by Luttinger to take into account the externally applied thermal gradient). And $L_{\alpha\gamma}^{(i)}$ are the transportation coefficients.

I want to understand the meaning of these two equations. I know that the first term in square brackets of $(2.13a)$ equation means the electrical current in $\alpha$ direction is proportional to the electric field in $\gamma$ direction. A similar argument is true for thermal current in the $(2.13b)$ equation.

What is the physical meaning of the rest of the terms in both equations?

Comment: Related  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754689/226902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Onsager Reciprocal Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations), see also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451905/226902).
They are basically the generalization of the Fick's law of diffusion, or the Fourier law of thermal conduction, or Ohm's law...
It is not possible to "derive" any non-equilibrium rate law (Fick's, Fourier's, etc...) from equilibrium thermodynamics, simply because they are beyond the scope of the theory: this is why your relations are defined "phenomenological".

It is postulated that there is a linear relation between the "fluxes" $J^i_a$ and the "forces" $\partial_i X_a$, which are gradients of some generalized potentials $X_a$:

$$
J^i_a = L^{ij}_{ab} \partial_j X_b \, ,
$$

where $i$ is a spatial index and $a$ is the index counting the number of different fluxes.

In your case you have the spatial indexes $\alpha, \gamma$ but your matrix is not a square one in $a,b$: you have 3 potentials + 1 electric field (so, 4 potentials, as the electric field should arise from a potential as well), but only 2 fluxes. To really understand why it has been constructed in that way one should go trough all the details of the paper.

The original article of [Onsager (1931)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.37.405) is quite clear and has some concrete examples, but I personally suggest also the one of [Casimir (1945)](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.17.343).

Comment: Thank you for such helpful suggestions.